# GIMP - Pythonfu PDB Code For Colors>Desaturate>Color To Gray

Tags: gimp, batch-processing, python

I'm using GIMP 2.10.2 and there is an option here for Colors>Desaturate>Color To Gray which works nicely by removing unnecessary gray shades from the photo.

However, I have about 200 photos which need to be processed this way, so I tried to use Python-Fu scripts to batch process multiple files. However, I can't seem to find this particular script to call this function.

There is GIMP-drawable-desaturate which doesn't really work too well. Does anyone know of a PDB script for the "Colors>Desaturate>Color To Gray"

Thanks,

Comment: If the GEGL code can not be scripted you may see if there is a GMIC-filter that meets your needs. [GMIC filters are scriptable](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/114250/12941).

Comment: You can also use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#grayscale) for such an operation.

Comment: @xenoid Indeed, I've tested the function and works fine, but I'm unsure of the needs of Dave. I hope that API for GEGL tools will be available one day.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Thanks for the tip, I took a look at Imagemagick, but I couldn't really find an equivalent to the "Color to Gray" tool. To expand on my needs, the photo is pages from a book with some texts and pictures on it which I want to print out, so I want to remove shadows, and highlight the text. I found the C2G the best for this. Unfortunately, it looks like it cannot be done at the moment, so I might have to do this manually for each picture

Comment: You can also use a script invoking **GEGL [command-line](http://gegl.org/commandline.html) executable**, chaining the available operations. You can find here an example of the use of [GEGL with **c2g**](http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/19125-gegl-run-c2g-batch-in-command-line) option. I've performed a few quick test on Windows and sometimes I got a buffer error when the process was almost ended, resulting in some points unprocessed. I suggest you to give a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C2G is more than `Color>Desaturate`, it also does some form of grayscale HDR/tone-mapping, so the usual desaturation techniques are not a replacement.

Unfortunately, at the same time C2G is part of a set of "GEGL tools" for which there is currently no API in Gimp, so I don't think there is a way to code the equivalent of C2G in a script, until these tools have a matching scripting API.

Comment: Please add this information to your short answer to expand it. Then we can remove these comments.

Comment: GEGL provides a [command-line executable](http://gegl.org/commandline.html), which can be used in scripts. Can you update your answer, please?